# C free variables declared inside function

Tags: c, function, memory-leaks, malloc, free

Imagine this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXSTRSIZE 2048    

int main()
{
    char *str;

    str = get_string();

    return 0;
}

char * get_string()
{
    char temp[MAXSTRSIZE], *str;

    fgets(temp,MAXSTRSIZE,stdin);
    str = malloc( sizeof(char) * (strlen(temp) + 1) );
    strcpy(str, temp);

    return str;
}
```

Do I need to free() the `temp` variable in function `get_string`?
What if did the `get_string` code inside the `main()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

free call applies only for dynamically allocated memory and not for static memory allocations

so if there is anything allocated dynamically using malloc/calloc needs to be freed when ever the reference count to the specified memory block will reach to zero, on the other hand statically allocated memory must not be freed at all, the program itself I suppose will not have right to free the memory allocated statically

in case you try to free static memory compiler ideally throws a warning at compile time like below
**warning: attempt to free a non-heap object**

in case, where the warning is ignored will present a nice runtime crash at free

* glibc detected  *./a.out: free(): invalid pointer:**

**never attempt to free a non-heap object**

Answer (score 3):

The caller will need to make sure `str` is freed. `temp` was not dynamically allocated, so you cannot free it.

Answer (score 3):

You must `free()` whatever you `malloc()`, it does not matter when or where but it must be happen to prevent a memory leak. When `free()` is called, the pointer must not be dereferenced again.

Note that `get_string()` must be declared or defined prior to `main()`.

Comment: ups, yes i forgot that, it's just sample code but i'll correct it, thanks :)

Comment: I can't edit it, must be a moderator. They say it's mostly code

Comment: One more question. If i needed that `str` var untill the very end of `main`, should i free it anyway (just because I `malloc()` it)?

Comment: Basically you don't have to, since the OS will free it anyway, but it is a good practice to free it, since you might in the future cut & paste it into some function, and forget to add `free()` there.

Comment: @Miguel, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10223677/when-a-program-terminates-what-happens-to-the-memory-allocated-using-malloc-that

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to (MUST NOT) free the `temp` variable, but you need to free `str` in your `main` (as it's `malloc`ed in get_string).

Comment: I think "do not need" might be understood as if it is optional.

Comment: Sorry, surely 'must not' is meant there. I'll add it to the answer. Thanks.