# Exception handling through signal communication in multiprocess programs in C

Tags: c, architecture, signals, multiprocess, systems-programming

We're currently grappling with an issue in a **multiprocess program** that involves the use of **signals** to safely terminate its **child processes**.

In our setup, a parent process sends a signal to its child processes to terminate and free all resources when it encounters a critical error (e.g., failure in `malloc()`, `pipe()`, or `fork()`). This strategy is designed to prevent unpredictable behavior due to the interdependencies among the child processes.

The challenge arises when we experience a sporadic double free within our main struct, which is accessible across most of our functions. Here's the situation:

Suppose a child process is in the midst of freeing a variable from the main struct (let's say an array).
The process of iterating through the array and freeing each element is of course not instantaneous. If the function that frees the array is midway through this operation and the process receives a signal (which triggers the signal handler to free the main struct and terminate the process), we end up with a double free for the first half of the array that has already been freed.

We already found out that `free()` is not an async-signal-safe function and should not be called in signal handler functions.

This brings us to our central query:

**What is a good heuristic to follow to define the timing for checking exception handling flags set by signal handling functions?**

What are safe and elegant strategies to tackle this issue?

Thanks in advance for your input. Every response is valuable!

**We considered two possible solutions:**

1. Limitting signal handler functions to merely setting a global flag, which then needs to be checked frequently during the regular program flow to determine if an abort is necessary. However, this does not seem very elegant.

   - What would be a good timing to check the state of this flag?

     - Before every request of more ressources from the OS (`malloc()`, `pipe()`, `fork()`)?
     - Before returning from any function?
2. Setting each pointer to `NULL` immediately after it has been freed.

   - Is there a risk that a signal might arrive right after a pointer has been freed but before it's been set to `NULL`?

Comment: 2.  Yes, there is a (small) risk of unfortunate timing.  Sod’s Law therefore dictates that it will happen.

Comment: If the child is about to exit, does it need to free the memory (or any other resources)?

Comment: Consider blocking the signal while doing work such as freeing the array so that the signal is only delivered when it is safe for the child to receive it.

Comment: It is not necessary to free allocated memory at program termination.  The OS will recover it anyway.  It is especially unnecessary to free memory at *abnormal* program termination. In an abnormal termination scenario, it is unwise to trust anything about program state, so the best alternative is usually to just stop.  That is, let the signal handler call `_exit(1)` or `abort()` or maybe `exit(1)`.

Comment: I set each pointer to null after free axiomatically (so use-after-free causes a segfault). In a commercial mission critical realtime application, I did the set-a-global approach of (1). Since it's sufficient to make such a global `volatile` (vs. using atomics), checking it is low overhead. Where to place a check depends on what the process is doing. I made it time based. The process could/should not go for X amount of time without doing the check. This dictated where to place checks within loops.

Comment: My situation was a little more complex. It was multithread and not multiprocess. It used SysV IPC messages for "normal" communication. The program had to stop cleanly and restart without any delay. So, I set a global (no signal needed because of threading) and used a "stop" message. Each thread would save a "watchdog" timestamp at the top of its event loop. The main thread would check these timestamps.

Comment: If any thread got "stuck" (abnormal condition), the main thread would set the global, and send signals to all threads. The threads would dump state information (for post-mortem debugging), set an "in-idle/safe state" flag and sleep wait. The main thread would watch for these flags. When all threads were in the "safe" state (or enough time passed), the main thread would sent signals to force termination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A strategy could be to set the members that are freed to `NULL` just before calling free:

```
for(...){
    void *mem = arr[i];
    arr[i] = NULL;
    free(mem);
}
```

It's [safe to call `free` on the `NULL`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6084233) values when (half of) the array was freed already: nothing will happen.

Now the only potential problem would be that the process might be interrupted between setting the member to `NULL` and calling `free`, so that one member won't be freed.

However, as the comments noted, if the program is terminating anyway, it should not be necessary to call free at all. The OS will clean up all memory used by the process anyway. In fact, it [may even be harmful](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6347182).

Comment: That's a neat idea.  In principle, you've swapped a double free for a missed free, but (in general) a missed free is a lot less serious than a double free.